# Autocomplete styles through the include php function in PhpStorm

Tags: php, css, autocomplete, include, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm and I love it, especially the auto-complete feature. I tried to use the autocomplete while including the CSS files with the "include" function, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php include("head.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="menu" class="heigth-100 bg-blue">
            <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="heigth-100 bg-gray padding">
            <h2 class="I-want-to-autocomplete">Home</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the function include(head.php); are my css files. But once this is done, the auto-complete stops working because they are not directly linked to the document.

Is there any way that auto-complete founds the styles in the include function?

Comment: it seems that if you have no style files on the page, phpstorm should take all of them from your project for autocomplete, BUT if you have one style in the page, and other styles included with an include directive, the included ones will not show on autocomplete, maybe this could be a bug...